# How to rotate an image with content on the same spot?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have an image like below

[image]

then I want to rotate it, but I don't want its position to be changed.
For example the output should look like below

[image]

If I do `imrotate`, it will change its position. Is there any other way to rotate this without changing its position?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`imrotate`](http://mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imrotate.html) function rotates the *entire* image around the specified angle. What you want is to rotate only a part of the image. For that you'll have to specify which part you want to rotate. Formally speaking, this is the rectangle in which this symbol is located.

The coordinates of this rectangle can be found by selecting all rows and columns, where any pixel is black. This can be done by taking the sum over all rows, finding the first and last non-zero entries there, and doing the same over all columns.

```
sx=find(sum(im==0,1),1,'first');
ex=find(sum(im==0,1),1,'last');
sy=find(sum(im==0,2),1,'first');
ey=find(sum(im==0,2),1,'last');
```

The relevant part of the image is then

```
im(sy:ey,sx:ex)
```

Now you can rotate only this part of the image and save it to the same location within the whole image:

```
im(sy:ey,sx:ex) = imrotate(im(sy:ey,sx:ex),180);
```

with the desired result:

[image: result]

**Note:** this will only work for 180° angles, such as the example you provided. If you rotate by any other angle, e.g. 90° or even arbitrary angles, such as 23°, the output of `imrotate` will not have the same size as the input, so the assignment `im(sy:ey,sx:ex) = ...` will always throw an error.

Comment: This answer is correct, but for angles other than 180 degree it might cut off corners because the image does not fit the rectangle region after rotating.

Comment: Yes, you are right. This just works for 180 degree rotations, as the example in the question. For all other angles, an error will occur. I'll highlight that in the answer.

Comment: @hbaderts thanks for the answer, can you please add something else to your answer? how can I detect that image 1 is the same as image 2 but rotated?. what I want to do is that I have a bunch of these images, I want to detect which ones are similar (just rotated) and then rotate them as the first image . Is it possible to do?

Comment: @Brian: that is a totally new question, please ask a new question or search for an already existing one. (I am sure we already had the question, but can't find it right now). But before you do it, does this answer your original question? If so please mark this answer as accept, otherwise comment why it does not answer your question.

Comment: @Daniel Yes, this helped me a lot , so I accepted it. Thanks. I will ask a new question